# Input string for parsing CSV file not in correct format

Tags: c#, sql, linq, csv

I am trying to store a CSV file containing the following data to a list:

[image: CSV_Data.png]

I have the following code which successfully saves the CSV to App_Data folder:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> CSVProducts;

        public static IEnumerable<Product> CSVToList(HttpPostedFileBase CSVFile)
        {

            if (CSVFile == null || CSVFile.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No file has been selected for upload or the file is empty.");
            }

            // saves the file into a directory in the App_Data folder
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(CSVFile.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
            CSVFile.SaveAs(path);


            CSVProducts = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                          let columns = line.Split(',')
                          select new Product
                          {
                              Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                              Barcode = columns[13],
                              Name = columns[1],
                              CategoryName = columns[9],
                              Description = columns[2],
                              Price = int.Parse(columns[4])
                          };

            return CSVProducts;
        }
```

However, the LINQ query to get a list gives the following error message:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 


Line 31:             CSVProducts = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
Line 32:                           let columns = line.Split(',')
Line 33:                           select new Product
Line 34:                           {
Line 35:                               Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),

Source File: C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Website\Models\Repository.cs

Line: 33
```

When I debug in Visual Studio, I can't see what's inside the variables inside the LINQ query, but I can see what is inside CSVProducts and the 'Current' property for it has a value of null.

This is the class for Product and Category:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool ShowOnIndex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And what's the value of `columns[0]` when the error happens?

Comment: It looks like `columns[0]` is the ProductID?

Comment: This is basically a parsing issue. As per your code you are doing parsing on two columns which is 0 & 4. Please check those values. There are some non-numeric characters in it.

Comment: Make sure there's no whitespace in any values in column 0.

Comment: When I debug in Visual Studio, I can't see what's inside the variables inside the LINQ query, but I can see what is inside CSVProducts and the 'Current' property for it has a value of null.

Comment: Then you likely have an empty cell somewhere. You can put filters on your file in Excel to help find the culprit.

Comment: Your fourth column, Price, is written as decimal, '1.19', and you're parsing it as integer, `Price = int.Parse(columns[4])`, parse it as  a double or float. Also, ensure your data has no comma in it, if it has a comma your split will break, splitting a CSV file is not a matter of splitting just by the sepparator as the data can be quoted and escaped.

Comment: ...using a tool like CSVHelper which has already encountered this and many, many other csv related issues, you'd be done by now.

Comment: Is it possible that your CSV file has got quotes around the field? `"21432",....` will split to be `"21432"`, which can't be parsed to int because of `"`. Also, consider using a CSV parsing library instead of doing it yourself. Check out `CsvHelper` (no affiliation, but i am using it on a current project) https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys in the comment section.

The reason why the LINQ query gave that error was because the data-type for the Price property in the Product class was `Decimal`. I initially was Parsing an `Int` inside the query for the Price value: `Price = int.Parse(columns[4])`.

I changed it to `Price = decimal.Parse(columns[4])` and now the LINQ query successfully parses through the Excel CSV file and stores each record in an IEnumerable list of Products. Thanks again guys. Love you all. :)